# How do you add dynamic queryParams to Backbone pageableCollection before syc

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to Backbone and I am trying to add extra parameter offset to queryParams before fetch sync occurs as the API does not support page, this is what I have tried to intercept the sync before sending options but it doesn't work, does anyone know how to achieve this?

```
Backbone.PageableCollection.extend({
        model: Entities.Role,
        url: function () {
            return App.API + 'role';
        },
        mode: "server",
        state: {
            pageSize: 15,
            order: 1,
            firstPage: 1,
            currentPage: 1
        },
        // You can remap the query parameters from `state` keys from
        // the default to those your server supports
        queryParams: {
            offset: 0,
            totalPages: null,
            totalRecords: null,
            sortKey: "sort",
            pageSize: "max"
        },
        sync: function(method, model, options){
            var defer = $.Deferred();
            options.beforeSend=function(xhr) {

                options.data.offset=(parseInt(model.state.currentPage) - 1) * model.state.pageSize;
                model.queryParams.offset=(parseInt(model.state.currentPage) - 1) * model.state.pageSize;

                defer.resolve(method, model, options);

            }
            return defer.promise(Backbone.sync(method, model, options));

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:
you dont need to use defer - just works with:

```
sync: function(method, model, options){
            options.data.offset=(parseInt(model.state.currentPage) - 1) * model.state.pageSize;
            model.queryParams.offset=(parseInt(model.state.currentPage) - 1) * model.state.pageSize;
            return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
}
```